# How to start kafka in minikube

Tags: apache-kafka, minikube

I am wondering the easiest way to start kafka?

with downloaded zip file, I can start kafka within 10 seconds, tried a google search, the most easier one also took 15 mins.

Answer (score -1):

The [Strimzi quickstart page](https://strimzi.io/quickstarts/) walks through the exact steps you need. That project is generally considered the "easiest" (+ free) way to use Kafka on Kubernetes. (I am not affiliated with this project)

> easiest way to start kafka?

Use the tarball from the official site. Using Kubernetes is not the easiest way to start *anything*.

Comment: Strimzi the name is enough to scare the beginner away, and the yml file configurations.

Comment: You're the one that tagged the question with minikube. If you don't want to use k8s or deal with yaml, then almost all the cloud providers offer Kafka

Comment: it doesn't sound easy to start a kafka instance with minikube, I am new to k8s and tried to understand the power of it.

Comment: I can't help you, then. You're the one that wanted minikube. It isn't that hard. `minikube start` `kubectl apply -f kafka-operator.yaml` `kubectl apply -f topics.yaml`... Write producer + consumer code, then containerize those, then deploy into k8s. Will take you a few minutes to follow those steps listed here https://strimzi.io/quickstarts/

Comment: it got almost 17k lines of configuration, can't say it is easy, while my intension is to create a dev only mini kafka cluster. While in most enterprise network, can't use strimzi and it's images directly.

Comment: Then use Helm or Bitnami operator. You still need to use YAML. There's literally no way to interact with k8s without having it at some level